# sum of amounts (function)

Tags: python, odoo

hello i want to calculate the sum of amounts like the photo

[image]

i tried this function but it doesn't work any suggestions plz

```
 _name = 'obj.ghb'    
_description = 'objet ghb'                           
@api.one
@api.depends('tax_line_ids.montant')    
def compute_total( self):   
for record in self:         
    total=sum([line.montant for line record.tax_line_ids])
    _columns = {      
        'nomprojet': fields.char('Nom du projet'),     
        'responsable': fields.char('Responsable GHB'),      
        'client': fields.char('Client'),      
        'contactclient': fields.char('Contact du client'),       
        'total': fields.float('Total', compute='compute_total', store='True'),
```

Comment: But you calculate the sum **per record**?

Comment: Well your indentation is wrong. Is that what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @khelwood: the syntax is wrong as well: the list comprehension for `sum` is incorrect.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem And not only that, but the `dict` declaration never reaches a closing brace. Seems like there are lots of issues, but since the OP doesn't give a clear description of their problem I thought I would stop at one.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem khelwood thanks for your answers i checked my indentation it's ok but when i put numbers on amount column on my view and try to save that in order to have the sum i have that error " File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20161125\server\openerp\addons\somme lundi\objects\chargefixee.py", line 33, in get_total
KeyError: 'montant'" which is on my function exactly on  total=sum([line.montant for line record.tax_line_ids])

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can solve your problem.

I suppose you are using odoo, and the relationship of ghb and tax_line_ids is `One2many`.

If my guess is right, you can follow this:

In odoo, the `api.depends` don't know when the One2many field changed, so it doesn't work.

Here is my way, You can rewrite the write function of the ghb model, if you find the tax_line_ids changed, you should call the `compute_total` function.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks for you answer i used another function but i have the same problem this is my new function (   
 def onchange_total( self, cr, uid, ids,montant, context = {} ):  
      data={}        
for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):            data['montant'] + = montant or False   
     return {'value': data} )
and i add it to my xml fields

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: it's ok thanks it works :)

Comment: that's the new function
def _amount_total(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context=None):        res = {}        for r in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):            res[r.id] = sum(r.obj_ghb_parent.mapped('montant'))        return res

Comment: congratulations

Answer (score 0):

try this in your xml form: `<field name="montant" string="total"  sum="montant total"/>`

Comment: thanks for your answer  in fact i used that but i need to save that result in the data base that's why i need a function because when we use that the result it's not saved on database

Comment: not return in your compute function. you just need to assign total : ex : record.total = "all montant"